# Dynamic drop down of child terms and then drop down posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I'm building a kind of selection tool. I have 9 parent taxonomies. Each one has some children and those all have posts.

I have the top level taxonomy displaying. However, I'm not quite sure how to get the child terms of each. My code is below.

```
 <div class="padded-panel">
                <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                        'category_name'    => $term->slug,
                        'orderby'          => 'date',
                        'order'            => 'DESC',
                        'post_type'        => 'equipment',
                        'suppress_filters' => true,
                    );
                    $posts = get_posts( $args );
                    // echo "<pre>";
                    // echo  print_r($posts);
                    // echo "</pre>";
                ?>  

                <!-- <form action="page-estimator2.php" method="post"> -->
                    <select class="select-model" name="model">
                        <option value=""> Select a model </option>
                        <?php 
                            foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
                            <?php $field = get_field("price_high", $post->ID); ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"> <?php echo $post->post_title; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php 
                            $post_id = $_POST['model']; 
                             echo "<h1>".$post_id."</h1>";
                        ?>
                    </select>
                <!-- </form> -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the child term of an parent you can use get_terms function

Here you can provide 
**hide_empty** as false ( this will list all term )
**parent** as the parent term id ( this will return the term related to that parent id

```
$tax_id = $term->term_id; 
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => $tax_id,
) );
```

Comment: What is the post_tag supposed to be? I've used the get_terms but for whatever reason it was pulling in EVERY term.

Comment: post_tag is the the name of your taxonomy. You can replace that by any custom taxonomy